# Me devuelve object object por consola

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo un programa con distintas clases. una alumno y otras profesores. el programa lo que debería hacer es recibir los datos y crear los **`.json`** de cada uno. hasta ahí todo bien. luego tengo que poder buscar datos y poder eliminarlos. las funciones ya están creadas. lo que falla es que cuando muestro por pantalla con un console.log si quiero borrar cierta ${persona} me lo devuelve como `object object`

```
eliminarPersona(propiedad:any,valor:string|number){
    let busqueda= readlineSync.question('¿Que desea ELIMINAR? Alumno= 1 ||| Profesor = 2: ')
    if(busqueda == '1') {
        const alumno=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./DATA/alumno.json'));
        for (let i = 0; i < alumno.length; i++) {
            if(alumno[i][propiedad]=== valor){
                let consulta = (readlineSync.question(`¿esta seguro que desea Eliminar a este Alumno: ${alumno[i]}?, SI / NO`)).toLocaleUpperCase();
                if(consulta== 'SI'){
                    alumno.splice(i,1)
                    console.log(`el alumno ${alumno[i]} a sido eliminado`)
                    fs.writeFileSync('./DATA/alumno.json',JSON.stringify(alumno,null,2));
                    return alumno;
                }else if(consulta== 'NO'){
                    console.log('no se a eliminado ningun alumno');
                }else{
                    console.log('comando incorrecto vuelva a intentar');
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando imprimes dentro de un console.log() un string junto a un objeto, debes convertir el objeto en una cadena de texto para que pueda ser mostrada, supongamos que quieres imprimir el objeto 'animal' y que se muestre correctamente:

```
const animal = {
  nombre: 'firulais',
  tipo: 'perro',
  color: 'rojo'
}
```

Podes pasar el objeto a cadena con JSON.stringify()

```
console.log(`animal: ${JSON.stringify(animal)}`)
```

Usar dos console.log separados, uno para la cadena y otro para el objeto

```
console.log('animal: ')
console.log(animal)
```

O implementar una funcion que reciba un objeto y que devuelva una cadena representando las propiedades y los valores de ese objeto

```
function objToString(obj){
  let objstring = '{ ';
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((elem) => {objstring += `${elem[0]}: ${elem[1]}, `})
  return objstring = objstring.slice(0, -2) + ' }'
}

console.log('animal' + objToString(animal))
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!! funciono!!